# how to dynamically set the choices of a choice field in django DRF serializer through __init__ or __new__ method?

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I am trying to dynamically set the choices of a choice field in django serializer class

I want to pass the choices (dynamically) to it and it set it for me

The simplified version of the project is this

```
# urls
urlpatterns = [
    path("cat", CatView.as_view(), name="cat")
]
```

I have tried different things and they don't work. I am sharing one of them here

I even had to use the private methods (which I would prefer not to) of the field but still not successful

```
# serializers
class CatSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=[])

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        name_choices = kwargs["names"]
        f = CatSerializer._declared_fields["name"]
        f._set_choices(name_choices)
        f.__dict__["_kwargs"]["choices"] = name_choices
        obj = super().__new__(cls)

        return obj

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.pop("names")
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

```
# views
class CatView(APIView):

    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        self.names = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = CatSerializer
        return serializer_class(
            *args, **kwargs,
            names=self.names
        )

    def post(self, request):

        request_body = request.body
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            data=json.loads(request_body),
        )
        is_data_valid = serializer.is_valid()
        if is_data_valid:
            serialized_data = serializer.data
            return Response({"message": "success", "serialized-data": serialized_data})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I now see this error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `CatSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `CatSerializer` instance.
Original exception text was: 'CatSerializer' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

it fails in views when it tries to get the data here `serialized_data = serializer.data`

this is another question with some variations that I have not yet figured out to solve and not received a response on.
[problem initializing django serializer with extra vars to be used in choice field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74671297/problem-initializing-django-serializer-with-extra-vars-to-be-used-in-choice-fiel)

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution so far ?

Comment: no. not a clean one like what I am asking above

Comment: So how did you end up doing it ?